# Why will WTForms submit again when I refresh the page?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I created the following form:

```
class ContentForm(Form):
    content = StringField(u'write here' , validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField(u'Let them know' )
```

When I submit, things seem to work.  However, when I refresh the page afterwards, the form is submitted again.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redirect after making a POST request.  Otherwise, the browser will do what you're experiencing (the behavior has nothing to do with WTForms).

```
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['GET', 'POST']
def my_form():
    form = ContentForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do stuff
        return redirect('my_form')  # or wherever

    return render_template('my_form.html', form=form)
```